# .Net Standard Microsoft.Win32 does not contain OpenFileDialog() Method

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-standard

I am trying to open the file dialog in my WPF application which is a .Net Core app and uses a .Net Standard Library where all my code lives. However, when I tried the OpenFileDialog() method which inherits from Microsoft.Win32 namespace, it says "the name OpenDialog does not exist in the current context" and that is the recurring error even after adding the namespace manually. However. when I tried this in my .netcoreapp, it works just fine. Bringing me to the conclusion that this is probably a problem with .netstandard only. My question is what is the best fix to this, I cannot put the code in my .NetCore WPF app, so the only other alternative is to create a new project for the sole purpose of opening the file dialog which I find a bit too much. Please does anyone have any alternatives, or perhaps I am doing things wrong. I would appreciate all your contributions.

Comment: .NET Standard is cross-platform and the class you want to use clearly runs only on Windows. What would `OpenFileDialog` do on Linux? The problem is in the code and the assumptions made, not .NET Standard

Comment: Besides, in .NET 5 you can create libraries that target Windows explicitly by using `net5.0-windows`. There's no need for .NET Standard in .NET 5+. The equivalent is `net5.0` without a platform specifier

Comment: `What would OpenFileDialog do on Linux?`, good question beat me to it ;)

Comment: If you only want your application to run on Windows then you can reference the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) from a .Net Standard class library. Obviously if you do that and try to call it from a non-Windows program, it will cause a runtime exception.

Comment: In other words, if your final app is Windows only, then many of its dependent class libraries should also be Windows only, aka .NET Core class libraries, not .NET Standard class libraries, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: After going through all the comments, I think I might as well just write the code into wpf app, considering it is window specific and really doesn't have anything to do with my back end code. All it does is open the file dialog. And I don't think that really does violate mvvm framework. what's your opinion on this

Comment: @Tobynate I think that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` is a Windows-specific API that is not part of .NET Standard.

You could create another class library that targets `netcoreapp3.1` or `net5.0-windows` and then reference your existing .NET Standard class library from this one, e.g.:

WPF App->`netcoreapp3.1` class library->`netstandard2.0` class library

The other option is to use the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) as an extension to your .NET Standard project.